# How can I submit my Drupal form to any other internal page?

Tags: php, forms, drupal-6

I'm having a problem with Drupal forms. Can't think of a way to solve it and I was wondering if any brain out there has the solution to my problem.

I have this form:

```
<?php
function mymodule_myform(){
  $form['#action'] = url('search/cards');
  $form['whatwhere']['what'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('What?'),
    '#maxlength' => 80,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Search'),
  );
}
?>
```

Which, as you can see, is supposed to submit all info to `www.example.com/search/cards`.
This will indeed submit my form to the desired URL. However, without the `mymodule_menu()` hook defining the path, it will end in a 404.

So I add:

```
<?php
function mymodule_menu(){
  $items['search/%'] = array(
    'title'  => t('Search Results'),
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_main',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'file' => 'mymodule.inc',
    );
}
?>
```

And, at `mymodule.inc` file I'll create my function `mymodule_main()`:

```
<?php
function mymodule_main(){
  print_r($_POST);
  die(); // ### Note the die(); ###

  return 'Just searched: '. $_POST['what'];
}
?>
```

If I leave it exactly like it is, of course PHP will end the script execution right after printing my form info on the screen. All good!

However, if I remove the `die()`, it seems the function is called twice, and the second call does not have $_POST filled up anymore.. Seems `mymodule_menu()` overrides in some way whatever the form submit handler is doing...

The question is: **How can I submit my form to any other internal page without having the 404 and keep my form info?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debate @ drupal forums ([which can be followed here](http://drupal.org/node/946374)) conclusion is that: it is not possible to have a menu callback handling form results. You can instead, use a form submit handler (as always) and then redirect to your menu callback.
It's not a POST to the menu callback but it's as good as it gets.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the method described in http://api.drupal.org/api/function/search_box_form_submit/6

```
function MODULE_block_form_submit($form, &$form_state)  
{  
    if (isset($_REQUEST['destination'])) {  
        unset($_REQUEST['destination']);  
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['edit']['destination'])) {  
        unset($_REQUEST['edit']['destination']);  
    }  

    $form_state['redirect'] = 'search/cards/'. trim($form_state['values']['whatwhere']);  
}
```

Comment: Hi MPD, as stated in the title, I want to SUBMIT (using POST) to other page, not just redirect with values at URL... Anyways, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly, but maybe your code conflicts with drupal's builtin **search** module?

Comment: Nope. That's not the case, I have a unique module name. `Search` it's just used in this example context. Thanks anyway.